# Behaviour of 2 resonant tuning forks in a vacuum

Tags: vacuum, resonance, harmonics

The scenario is the following. Two perfectly tuned resonant tuning forks A,B are placed in the same vacuum. [ Ideally the experiment is conducted when both A&B are in free fall]. Tuning fork A is struck. Now I know that the usual automatic answer to the question, 'Does B resonate in harmony with A' is, 'Without the presence of a medium [air] - of course not'.

Having looked, I can find ne reference to any such experiment being carried out. My question is; Because the answer seems so obvious, has the experiment actually been performed to confirm that this is indeed the case?

Comment: Technically, gravitational waves would cause a very weak coupling between the tuning forks, and so the second one would eventually start vibrating too.  But I will bet you a shiny dollar that this effect wouldn't be noticeable in a human lifetime, let alone in the ~10 seconds of free-fall you can get on Earth's surface.

Comment: there are differences between a medium and a vacuum and they are exploited, to use the tuning forks as detectors, as far as I uderstand. example https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4584

Answer (score 0):

The fact that sound does not propagate in vacuum was tested for the first time in the 17th century, when vacuum pumps became available. Athanius Kircher and Robert Boyle are some of the first experimenters. At that time it was an imprtant experiment, to decide if the sound need a medium or (according to alternative theory) is due to some special particles emitted by the source.
Nowadays it is classroom experiment and you can see experiments on youtube demonstrating the same phenomenon (or the absence of). The free fall is irrelevant to this. Why would you think that it make any difference?
Of course, if the two tuning forks are supported by the same table or postamet, the sound will be transmitted through this solid medium, even if the whole system is in vacuum. So you have to define the conditions of your setup more specifically in order to know waht will actaully happen.